# Repair a ripped touchscreen cable

Tags: cables, repair, touchscreen

I have an Ampire AM800480STMQWT00 touchscreen display. In the course of testing the device, the cable for the touchscreen proper got ripped by accident.

Is it possible at all to repair the cable itself, or would I be forced to simply acquire a brand new touchscreen to mount on the display? I tried searching around for the touchscreen display I have but there's not a lot of information available on it.

The actual rip is towards the end of the cable that would be plugged into a device.

Comment: can we get a link to the device datasheet?

Comment: pics of cable? is it a flex cable? help us help you.

Comment: Too much information left out. Since that should have been obvious, it is unlikely this question can be salvaged. It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of really ghetto-fixing FFCs like this that I've found successful is to cut the cable where it ripped (straight across so you have an even end), and then scraping away at the insulation of the end that is to be inserted into the female mating connector. In order to get the FFC into the connector, sometimes it is necessary to reinforce the cable end by inserting it along with some thin plastic, or applying some tape to the back (to make it a bit thicker to have a firm fit inside the connector).

Keep in mind, this assumes you have enough (lengthwise) of the FFC remaining after the cut to work with. If you don't, you'll need a new FFC/display panel.

(FFC = Flat Flexible Cable)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a typical ribbon cable you're talking about, there was a discussion a few months back on [another forum](http://bbs.homeshopmachinist.net/showthread.php?t=53305&highlight=flex%20cable) , with plenty of "how-we-done-it-good-up-our-way" stories and advice, etc., ranging from "you're s.o.l." to "piece of cake".